# CSS Ease-in-out to full screen

Tags: html, css

I have a black background div of a size which contains an image.

```
  <div id="Banner">
  <img onclick="expand();" src="hola.jpg">
  </div>

  #Banner {
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#000000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  }

<script type="text/javascript">
  function expand(){
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['height'] = '250';
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['width'] = '250';
  }
</script>
```

So when the user clicks on the image, the div transitions to 250, 250.

My problem is that, i want it to to transition to full screen. The following javascript
function does expand to fullscreen but the transition effect doesn't come. I need to do it from a javascript code without jquery.

```
  function expand(){
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['position'] = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['height'] = '100%';
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['width'] = '100%';
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['top'] = '0';
    document.getElementById('Banner').style['left'] = '0';
  }
```

Please advice.

**Update : Solution**

Roger below has provided with an alternative solution. This takes care if the document
has already been scrolled and is another place. Will expand the div to full browser screen.

```
sz=getSize();        //function returns screen width and height in pixels
currentWidth=200;
currentHeight=200;
scalex=sz.W/currentWidth;
scaley=sz.H/currentHeight;
transx=0-((document.getElementById("Banner").offsetLeft+(currentWidth/2))-(sz.W/2))+document.body.scrollLeft;
transy=0-((document.getElementById("Banner").offsetTop+(cuttentHeight/2))-(sz.H/2))+document.body.scrollTop;
transx = transx.toString();
transy = transy.toString();
document.getElementById("Banner").style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate('+transx+'px,'+transy+'px) scale('+scalex+','+scaley+')';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by transition effect you mean an animation, you have to divide the changes to the propperties in the time you want it to animate; remeber: an animation occurs in time. If you just set

```
document.getElementById('Banner').style['width'] = '100%';
```

It will be executed at once, you need to instead, go to X% to 100% in Y milliseconds; e.g.

```
function changeWidth(){
    var initialWidth = document.getElementById('Banner').style['width'];
    var stepValue = (CALCULATE_YOUR_FULL_WIDTH - currentWith)/1000;

    var animate = function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('Banner');
        element.style['width'] = element.style['width'] + stepValue;
    }

    setInterval(animate, 1);
}
```

I hope you get the idea, I didn't test it so i can't asure it works.

```
    function changeWidth(){
        var initialWidth = 200;
        var stepValue = (1000 - initialWidth)/1000;

        var currentSize = initialWidth;
        var animate = function(){
            currentSize = currentSize + stepValue;
            var element = document.getElementById('Banner');
            element.style['width'] = (currentSize + stepValue)*1 + 'px';
        };

        setInterval(animate, 1);
    };
```

This works, you will have to work from it because it's just ugly :P, read the jquery functions that make this to see how the do it, that's a good start.

**Edit**

Well, I ended up doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/HJwPF/

Comment: Trying it. Works. I need to expand 2d in both sides from the div rectangle so that it fills the whole browser.

Comment: @AdityaSingh You have to do the same for every propperty you want to change. i.e. height, top, left. Don't expect to get full code here, I gave you an starting point and told you what was the problem in your initial concept. If you just copy/paste the function instead of trying to understand it, you will gain nothing and that is not the purpose of stackoverflow. As I told you, read the animate function of jQuery and modify it at your needs, nobody will code for you. In my function, all you have to do is add the code needed for the height.

Comment: @AdityaSingh I ended up doing it :P

Comment: Super cool ! I got it too yesterday night using webkit-transform. Updated original post. I like your pure javascript approach. That should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If, when you mean full screen, you mean the actual browser **inner** available space, you can use the tips from this [link](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) to get the values and use them instead of 100% when assigning width and height.

Let me know if it helps.

**ADDED**

Code from link just in case it gets lost:

```
function getSize() {
    if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
       winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
       winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
        document.documentElement &&
        document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
       winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
       winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
       winW = window.innerWidth;
       winH = window.innerHeight;
    }

    return { W: winW, H: winH }
}
```

Comment: Tried. It expands in place and not to top left. I want the borders to animate from where it is to the full browser. The second javascript above works, just that it doesn't animate. Also the above code leaves white borders and scrollbars appear.

Comment: @Tallmaris I borrowed your function, hope it's Ok